# Bamboo CICD pipeline getting triggered in a loop with maven release

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bamboo, maven-release-plugin

I have a Bamboo CICD pipeline using maven build and release. Have created a trigger of type "`Repository triggers the build when changes are committed`" and my repository is BitBucket.

Whenever code is checked in or if there is a change in my repository, build pipeline is getting triggered. Last step of my build pipeline is maven release which updates and checks in the pom file. This check-in is in turn invoking the pipeline resulting in a loop. Is there any way this loop can be stopped  by not invoking the pipeline for pom file changes checked in by bamboo?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven release checks in the files with commit message "[maven-release-plugin]" and Bamboo plan ignores commits starting with the specified pattern. I had earlier updated the maven release commit message to satisfy my commit hooks hence Bamboo plan was always getting triggered. Have now updated the commit hook to accept the maven commits.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the plan, goto the Repositories tab and select your repository (or linked repository).

Scroll down to the bottom and expand Advanced Options.

There is a dropdown for "Include / exclude files", select "Exclude all changes that matches to the following pattern" then a textbox will appear underneath "File pattern" where you can specify a regular expression to express your pom file.

[Link to pattern examples](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO052/_planRepositoryIncludeExcludeFilesExamples?_ga=2.25234749.1479403392.1517319627-1365240128.1480009251)

Comment: Hi Richie, Thank you for the response. Guess the above mentioned option excludes matching files checked in by all users but I need to exclude only the checkins made by Bamboo. When a user checks in pom file, build should still be triggered automatically. Is it possible to ignore checkins made by Bamboo alone?

Comment: Not sure. Might be a way round it with commit hooks. Perhaps too much effort unless pom files are routinely committed alone.

Comment: @DeepakAkula Out of interest, why are you updating the pom?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, we are in the development phase of a completely new project, so new dependencies are getting added as per the requirements in each sprint. Anyhow, this issue is resolved now. Bamboo checks in the files using certain format and build plan ignores those comments. I had earlier added certain extra comments with maven release to satisfy Git commit hooks, now I have updated the hook to accept these Bamboo commits.